# How do I write a code for an f(x) equation to give its corresponding f(-x) in python?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to write a function that accepts inputs of coefficients for polynomial f(x) and returns the corresponding f(-x). This is what I have so far:

```
import numpy as np
coeff = [1, -5, 2, -5]
poly = np.poly1d(coeff)
print (poly)
```

This prints out:

```
1x³ - 5x² + 2x - 5
```

I'm stuck here, since using poly(-x) or any values of x calculates the whole equation itself. Is there any workaround here? What I only want is for the code to do f(-x) such that 1(-1)³ - 5(-1)² + 2(-1) + 5 prints out:

```
-1x³ - 5x² - 2x - 5
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are defining your polynomial by it's coefficients. I would instead define the variable `x` and let the module itself handle all the manipulations.

```
import numpy as np

x = np.poly1d([1,0])
p = x**3 - 5*x**2 + 2*x - 5
print(p(-x))
```

Comment: thank you! i might use this. i'm very new to using python. btw, additional question. what does x=np.poly1d([1,0]) do?

Comment: `x=np.poly1d([1,0])` created an instance of a class and called it x. That class has already been programmed to know what to do if it is multiplied, added, subtracted, or composed with another object made from x. Hence, once `x` is created, you can do things like `p(1-x)` or `p(-2*x)` or evaluate `(p(-x))(15)`, etc.

Comment: but i forgot that my inputs or variables shall be the coefficients of the polynomial. i dont think i can extract the coefficients from the 'p' here.

Comment: You can access the coefficients of p with `p.coefficients`. You can also access the coefficients of p(-x) with `p(-x).coefficients`.

Comment: i see. thank you very much. problem solved :)

Answer (score 0):

Just multiply by -1 to coeff list like below

```
import numpy as np
coeff = np.array([1, -5, 2, -5])
poly1 = np.poly1d(coeff)
print (poly1)
poly2 = np.poly1d(-1 * coeff)
print(poly2)
```

Comment: I believe the OP wants f(-x) not -f(x).

Comment: just use poly(-x)

Comment: The OP never defined `x`.

Comment: What do you want ? Do you want a function for calculating f(x), or just print the polynomial equation?

Comment: @DaisukeAkagawa just printing the polynomial equation with f(-x)